# COUNTIF / Matching and determining repeating data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I have question for EXCEL. I am looking to determine how many times each number repeats with another number in a data set.

If I have a data set:

Line 1 - 1 2 5

Line 2 - 1 2 10

Line 3 - 1 6 9 10

Line 4 - 1 2 8

Line 5 - 1 3 8 9

Line 6 - 1 7 8

Line 7 - 10 6 4

Line 8 - 5 4

Line 9 - 6 4

Line 10 - 7 6

Line 11 - 9

For example: how many times 1 shows in the same row as 2, how many times 6 shows with 10, etc. I am trying to determine a formula that could fill the table format following for easier visual representation:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10
```

Could the formula above be adapted to achieve my goal?

```
=COUNTIF(A1:F1,I$1)*COUNTIF(A1:F1,J$1)
```

Comment: So each line is in columns A:F with each number in a separate cell, correct?

Comment: Correct.  The values range between 1 and 10.  The formula I had found elsewhere on the forums and I am trying to adapt it for my purposes.  http://superuser.com/questions/856852/count-rows-where-several-values-appear-together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper column and concatenate the values into one cell with a `" "` between and on the ends of the string:

```
=CONCATENATE(" ",A1," ",B1," ",C1," ",D1," ")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then using that as the reference we can use COUNTIFS() to get the counts:

```
=IF(I$1<>$H2,COUNTIFS($E:$E,"* " & $H2 & " *",$E:$E,"* " & I$1 & " *"),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  This worked perfectly for what I needed.